# Accessing and moving bytes in X86 assembly

Tags: string, assembly, x86, att, endianness

I have several questions about memory and registers in X86 assembly:

1. I have a string `"abcdefgh"`, and register `%eax` holds a pointer to the string. Now I use `movl (%eax), %edx` to grab the first four bytes of the string into `%edx`. How are they stored in the register? Is the character `d` in the `%dl` register, or is it the character `a`?
2. When using `movb %eax, %dl` for example, which of `%eax`'s bytes does it actually move? The one in `%al` or the opposite one? Is it even possible to do this? Or should I use a pointer like this - `movb (%eax), %dh` - to take the first byte the pointer points to?

Comment: If you want to copy the low byte of `%eax`, use `mov %al, %dl`.  To move the 2nd byte, use `mov %ah, %dl`.  To get one of the other two bytes, copy/shift/mask, or use BMI1 `bextr`.  To extend, use `movsx` / `movzx` to sign/zero extend, like `movsx %al, %edx`.  Or `movsxbl (%eax), %edx` to sign-extend a byte from memory, pointed to by `%eax`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes is related to this, but uses Intel syntax.

Comment: Wait, so assuming EAX points to string `"abcd"`, does using `movb (%eax), %cl` move `a` or `d` to `%cl`?

Comment: m0skit0's answer is correct: A byte load from a pointer to the start of the string will load the first byte: `'a'`  More interesting is the fact that a 32b load from the same address into `%ecx` will still load `'a'` into `%cl`, opposite of what you'd get on a big-endian machine.  My comment was in response to the register-register move part of your question, where you copy a byte of `%eax`, rather than dereferencing it.

Comment: One final question: can I use `cmpb %bl, (%eax)` to compare the byte in `%bl` and the first byte that `%eax` points to?

Comment: Yup, of course.  `cmp` can have a memory operand as either the first or 2nd operand.  Also note that you only need the size suffix in cases where it's ambiguous (e.g. immediate and memory operand, like `cmpb $0xab, (%eax)` vs. `cmpl $0xab, (%eax)`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using the unusual GAS' syntax (source is the first operand, destination is the second one) and not Intel's :

> How are they stored in the register? Is the character d in the %dl
>   register, or is it the character a?

Since you're accessing the string as if it was a 32-bit number, endianness applies. x86 is little-endian so you get the least-significant byte at the lowest address, so DL will hold 'a' (0x61), and the whole EDX would be 0x64636261.

> When using movb %eax, %dl for example, which of %eax's bytes does it
>   actually move? The one in %al or the opposite one? Is it even possible
>   to do this?

That would give an syntax error because operands are of different size. You can't move 32 bits to 8 bits.

> Or should I use a pointer like this - movb (%eax), %dh - to take the
>   first byte the pointer points to?

If you want to access the data pointed by EAX and not EAX itself, then yes, that should work.